# Save as dialog missing in windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

Recently, I have been unable to download files because the "Save as" button did nothing. Now, I note that I can't even save something from MS Paint because the "Save as" Button does nothing too, and I cannot open anything, either. It seems that the component of windows that specifies those dialog boxes has went missing (but I don't get any error), or replaced by one that does nothing. How can I fix this? Is this a known problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The related library is `comdlg32.dll`, which is usually located in `C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll`. Try doing a system check-up by running the `sfc /scannow` command. In case any system file is missing or corrupted, the program will try restoring it. If required, you will be prompted to insert the Windows XP installation CD to get the missing files.

Comment: Also try clearing your temporary files from the system.

Comment: @and31415 Thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I need administrator credentials do to that I don't have them right now, but that does help me.

Comment: @TiagoƇ. Clearing temporary files is (almost)never a bad idea, but why would it help?

Comment: @chubakueno I had seen a similar issue http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/ie-7on-downloading-files-option-to-save-asopen/9ee22c03-8fc3-4225-9bde-ee0e8e3c0fe9

Comment: @chubakueno Even if you don't have admin rights you can still check yourself whether the file is actually there. Are you experiencing any other issues apart from the open/save dialogs?

Comment: @TiagoƇ. Thank you for the reference. Going give a try to the suggestions there.

Comment: @and31415 I get `You must be an administrator running a console session in order to use the Windows File Checker utility.` which is consistent with [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6ab9b06a-2fd1-40c6-8b4a-0a799c7da1a0/cannot-use-sfc-scannow?forum=winservergen). I don't have any other problems with this laptop that I know of right now.

Comment: @and31415 Thank you for your help and interest. There is a `Comdlg32.dll` there, with the caps included. There is also a `Comdlg32.ocx` and a `Comdlg32.dep`. I tried to open notepad and I got that the entrypoint to `PrintDlgExW` in `comdlg32.dll`(without caps this time) is missing, which confirms your suspicion.

Comment: @and31415 176128 bytes, both virtually and in disk. The version is 4.72.3510.2300. Yes, I am using Windows XP SP3.

Comment: The file got replaced by an older version: the `comdlg32.dll` file bundled with SP3 is version **6.00.2900.5512** (276992 bytes).

Comment: If the file not exist you need to add comdlg32.dll.  If it does exist it has probably been replaced by a old/incompatible version.  Either find a newer version on the XP CD or google it.

Comment: @and31415 I see! I don't have the rights to change the file, but now I know the problem. If you post it as an answer I would happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Analysis

The Windows API functions which handles those [dialog boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are located in the `comdlg32.dll` library file, which is usually located in `C:\Windows\System32`:

> The Common Dialog Box Library contains a set of dialog boxes for performing common application tasks, such as opening files, choosing color values, and printing documents.
>
> <sub>Source: [Common Dialog Box Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

In this case the file got replaced by an older version meant for Windows 9x:

```
Size: 176128 bytes
Version: 4.72.3510.2300
```

As a comparison, the following is the original file bundled with Windows XP SP3:

```
Size: 276992 bytes
Version: 6.00.2900.5512
```

This problem is called [DLL stomping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell#DLL_stomping), and usually occurs when a program overwrites a system library with an earlier, incompatible version. Running `notepad` quickly confirmed it:

> The procedure entry point PrintDlgExW could not be located in the dynamic link library comdlg32.dll.

## Resolution

You can perform a system check-up by running the `sfc /scannow` command. In case any system file is missing or corrupted, the program will try restoring it. When required you will be prompted to insert the Windows XP installation CD.

**Note** This procedure require administrator rights.

### Workaround

If you have access to a Windows XP SP3 setup media, you can get the original file by copying the `COMDLG32.DL_` file inside the `I386` folder. Then you have to decompress it by running the following commands from a command prompt:

```
cd /d "X:\Folder\containing\COMDLG32.DL_"
expand COMDLG32.DL_ comdlg32.dll
```

At this point you could boot any Linux live CD/DVD/USB, and then manually replace the old `comdlg32.dll` file with the correct one.

## References

- [Common Dialog Box Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [System File Checker (sfc)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491008.aspx)
- [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell)

Comment: You got a typo in `comdgl32.dll`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @chubakueno Fixed! It was in the error message; not a critical typo, at least. While I was writing the answer I took the occasion to provide additional info. Let me know if you have any other questions.